# UIView Animation - Easing Function not applied

Tags: xamarin.ios

Can anyone provide a hint why the easing curve in the code below does not have any effect. In fact not even the duration value seems to have an effect.

```
UIView.BeginAnimations("");

UIView.Animate(1, 0, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, delegate
{
    view.Alpha = 0.0f;

    var newFrame = new RectangleF(UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0].Frame.Right + 10, view.Frame.Top, view.Frame.Width, view.Frame.Height);
    view.Frame = newFrame;
},

delegate
{
    view.RemoveFromSuperview();
});

UIView.CommitAnimations();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling UIView.BeginAnimations first. You can either use the UIView.BeginAnimations - UIView.CommitAnimations or the UIView.Animate method, not both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

UIView.Animate(...) in 4.x+ does not require the BeginAnimations / CommitAnimations block. Just as a sanity check, are you calling UIView.Animate(..) from the main thread?